# there is a top and bottom gap

Tags: flutter, dart

hi i have remove the expanded , now the bold text of child has curly wave , what i did wrong over here.

below is my code i, please advice, thanks

```
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Introduction extends StatefulWidget {
  const Introduction({super.key});

  @override
  State<Introduction> createState() => _IntroductionState();
}

class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
      Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start),
        **child**: const Center(
            child: Image(
                height: 1000,
                width: 1000,
                image: AssetImage("lib/images/instruction.png"))),
      )
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: add image showing the actual output and your expected output

Comment: hey,, there i think you want to put Image widget into a column. am i right??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strongly advised to format your code with in-built Dart formatter. By doing that you can clearly see the structure and hierarchy of your code and widgets.

In your example you inside of **Scaffold** you have **Column** as a body widget

```
Scaffold(body: Column(children: [
```

And **Column** accepts a list of widgets, this is what square bracket is for. Then you are adding **Container** as the first child of the list, but inside that **Container** you add another **Column** as a child, and trying to pass another `**child**: const Center`. But it's done inside of **Container**, which accepts only 1 child argument, a single Widget (which can be Column again though, which accept a list of Widgets)

Your current hierarchy looks like this and incorrect:

```
Scaffold
 - Column
 -- Container
 --- Column
 --- Center 
 (It breaks before Image, because Container can only hold 1 Widget)
 ---- Image
```

Based on your requirements you should have one of the following hierarchies:

```
Scaffold
 - Column
 -- Container
 --- Center 
 ---- Image
```

```
class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
            child: Center(
              child: Image(
                height: 1000,
                width: 1000,
                image: AssetImage("lib/images/instruction.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or

```
Scaffold
 - Container
 -- Center 
 --- Image
```

```
class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        child: Center(
          child: Image(
            height: 1000,
            width: 1000,
            image: AssetImage("lib/images/instruction.png"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

or

```
Scaffold
 - Container
 -- Column
 --- Center 
 ---- Image
```

```
class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Image(
                height: 1000,
                width: 1000,
                image: AssetImage("lib/images/instruction.png"),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

removing your `Expanded` Widget will do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,` in Column class

Comment: hi thanks for the reply , am i too new to flutter, possible to help me on the editing of the code. i keep getting curly red line.

Comment: thanks for it, i guess the problem is on my png which is smaller so it does not max out the whole screen.